# Relational Database Design - To add a circular reference or not to add a circular reference

Tags: database-design, relational-database

Suppose you have a table of insurance policies like

```
Policies
PolicyID | CustomerID
       1 |          1
       2 |          1
       3 |          2
```

You want to track the revisions made to each policy, so you create a table like

```
PolicyRevisions
PolicyRevisionID | PolicyID |     EFDT |     EXDT | RevisionDate
               1 |        1 | 1/1/2014 | 1/1/2015 |     1/1/2014
               2 |        2 | 1/1/2014 | 1/1/2015 |     1/1/2014
               3 |        3 | 1/1/2014 | 1/1/2015 |     1/1/2014
               4 |        1 | 1/1/2014 | 3/1/2015 |     5/5/2014
```

Now, if you're building an application using this data, it's going to make sense to refer to an "active" policy revision that drives the application. My thought for doing this is to create an ActiveRevisionID foreign key field in the `Policies` table that points to a record in the `PolicyRevisions` table, but this is a little unsettling because it creates a circular reference.

Is this bad design?  Is there a better way?  If I go this route, what problems will I face down the road?

EDIT: I should have been more clear - I cannot assume that the most recent policy revision is the "active" one.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not a good idea, but it can be done. You have to make the PolicyRevisionID in the Policy table nullable, otherwise you can't add a Policy as there isn't a PolicyRevision. Similarly you can't add a PolicyRevision as there isn't a Policy. To get around that make PolicyRevisionID in Policy nullable, and you can add a Policy with a null PolicyRevisionID.

In this situation I would add a flag to PolicyRevision called Active. The precise implementation of that depends on some more data about your domain: can you have different Revisions active over the life of the policy? e.g. Policy 1 has Revision 1 active from 1 Jan 2014 to 31 Jul 2014, and revision 2 active 1 Aug 2014 to 1 Jan 2015? If so, you can have multiple revisions with Active = true and you have to validate somehow that the active ones don't overlap.

If not true, and only one is ever active, then the validation is a bit easier (it can be done via a trigger; when the new value is True set the value for all other Revisions of that Policy to false).

In general, circular dependencies are not a good idea.